# Akka Streams create new Source from result of previous Source in a graph

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I'm trying to create Graph that takes 1 input source, takes last element and produces new source. Currently I managed to do this only by materializing first stream with Sink.last.

`Source.fromFuture(curStream.runWith(Sink.last).map(last => createStreamFromOffset(last)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    val in = Source(1 to 10)

    val out = Sink.foreach(println)

    val concat = builder.add(Concat[Int](2))

    val f1 = Flow[Int].fold(0) { (acc, el) =>
      el
    }

    in ~> f1 ~> concat

    // creating new source from old stream last value
    in.via(f1).flatMapConcat(_ => Source(666 to 670)) ~> concat

    concat ~> out

    ClosedShape
  })
  g.run()
```